# Python BeautifulSoup - Using find_next while parsing invalid HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup in python to parse this [webpage](http://dansesportive.ffdanse.fr/compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592).

My goal is to get the table after the headline "Autre compétitions":

```
page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(website_link,proxies=proxy).text,'html.parser')
page.find("h3",text=u'Autres comp\xe9titions').find_next("table")
```

I manage to get the page, but the problem is the result I get with find is only the first cell of the header of the table:

```
<table class="gradient" id="tosort">
<tr>
<th class="gradient">Type</th></tr></table>
```

I thought that the problem comes from page being in unicode, so:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(path,proxies=proxy).text,'html.parser')
page.find("h3",text=u'Autres comp\xe9titions'.encode('utf-8')).find_next("table")
```

but I get the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parser from `html.parser` to `lxml` or `html5lib`.

If you don't have either of those parser installed, [here is the relevant Beautiful soup documentation on how to install different parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

```
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(website_link,proxies=proxy).text, 'lxml')
```

The HTML source code of the page that you are trying to scrape is invalid.

I just tested this out locally and the `lxml` and `html5lib` parsers are much more lenient and they were able to properly select the `table` element despite the invalid HTML. According to the documentation, the `html.parser` is not very lenient depending on your Python version.

More specifically, the invalid HTML that was causing the problem for the `html.parser` were the stray `div` tags in the `th` elements:

```
<th class='gradient'>Type</div></td>
```

As a result, the `html.parser` wasn't able to parse past the stray `div` tags, which resulted in it being unable to select the entire `table` element.

Comment: `html.parser` is so broken, I think bs4 document should remove it or add some warning information

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using the default parser.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> URL = 'http://dansesportive.ffdanse.fr/compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content,'lxml')
>>> heading = soup.find_all(string='Autres compétitions')
>>> heading
['Autres compétitions']

>>> heading[0].findNext('table')
<table class="gradient" id="tosort">
<tr>
<th class="gradient">Type
  </th><th class="gradient">Niveau
  </th><th class="gradient">Classe
  </th><th class="gradient">Série
  </th><td> </td>
<th class="gradient">Lat.
  </th><th class="gradient">St.
  </th><th class="gradient">10 d.
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td class="">Championnat</td>
<td class="">Régional</td>
<td class="">Adultes </td>
<td class="">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class=" left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-A-ABCDEF-L">x</a></td><td class=" left center"> </td><td class=" left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangelight">Championnat</td>
<td class="orangelight">Régional</td>
<td class="orangelight">Adultes </td>
<td class="orangelight">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="orangelight left center"> </td><td class="orangelight left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-A-ABCDEF-S">x</a></td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">Championnat</td>
<td class="">Régional</td>
<td class="">Juniors II </td>
<td class="">C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class=" left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-C-CDEF-L">x</a></td><td class=" left center"> </td><td class=" left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangelight">Championnat</td>
<td class="orangelight">Régional</td>
<td class="orangelight">Youths </td>
<td class="orangelight">B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="orangelight left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-J-BCDEF-L">x</a></td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">Championnat</td>
<td class="">Régional</td>
<td class="">Youths </td>
<td class="">B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class=" left center"> </td><td class=" left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-J-BCDEF-S">x</a></td><td class=" left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangelight">Championnat</td>
<td class="orangelight">Régional</td>
<td class="orangelight">Séniors I </td>
<td class="orangelight">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="orangelight left center"> </td><td class="orangelight left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-S-ABCDEF-S">x</a></td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">Championnat</td>
<td class="">Régional</td>
<td class="">Séniors II </td>
<td class="">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class=" left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-V-ABCDEF-L">x</a></td><td class=" left center"> </td><td class=" left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangelight">Championnat</td>
<td class="orangelight">Régional</td>
<td class="orangelight">Séniors II </td>
<td class="orangelight">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="orangelight left center"> </td><td class="orangelight left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-V-ABCDEF-S">x</a></td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="">Championnat</td>
<td class="">Régional</td>
<td class="">Séniors III </td>
<td class="">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class=" left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-W-ABCDEF-L">x</a></td><td class=" left center"> </td><td class=" left center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orangelight">Championnat</td>
<td class="orangelight">Régional</td>
<td class="orangelight">Séniors IV </td>
<td class="orangelight">A B C D E F </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="orangelight left center"> </td><td class="orangelight left center"><a href="compet-resultats.php?NumManif=1592&amp;Compet=Champ-R-X-ABCDEF-S">x</a></td><td class="orangelight left center"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```